# Difference between adding properties to constructor or prototype

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, prototype

I see two approaches to add properties to a Class.

1. Define properties in constructor
2. Define properties in prototype

I would like to know the difference in them. Here is the code and **[JsBin](http://jsbin.com/ijEVEqI/1/edit?html,js,console,output)**

```
var show = function() {
  console.log('Show started..');

  // Adding properties in constructor
  this.properties = {
    name: 'Testing javascript'
  };
};

show.prototype.getName = function() {
  console.log(this.properties.name);
};

// Adding properties to prototype
show.prototype.properties = {
  name: 'Testing prototype'
};

var myShow = new show();

myShow.getName();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Members of the prototype are shared for all instances:

```
var Person=function(name){
  this.obj.name=name;
};
Person.prototype.obj={name:"Default"};
var ben = new Person("Ben");
var leo = new Person("Leo");
console.log(ben.obj.name);//logs Leo
```

In the code above both ben and leo share the `obj` member. Behaviour (=functions) is usually put on the prototype because they don't change for instances. To have this on the prototype will save initialisation and memory because no matter how many instances you create the function on the prototype exists only once.

Members declared in the constructor function body with `this.someProp=...` are instance specific.

For more info on constructor functions and prototype you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941).

Comment: @blunderboy You're welcome. It takes some time to wrap your head around the prototype thing (took me some time) but once you got it it's quite simple.